# styling an element when checkbox is checked

Tags: css

```
<input type="checkbox" id="c1">
<label for="c1">c1</label>
<div>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

I want to style span when checkbox is checked. I tried below style but its not working.

```
input:checked ~ div span{
    background: red;
}
```

```css
input:checked~div span {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="c1">
<label for="c1">c1</label>
<div>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Its working fine @Mayur https://jsfiddle.net/0zwfkr17/16/

Comment: Its working just add content in the span to see it work

Comment: @NanditaAroraSharma can you solve the problem in this pen https://codepen.io/mayurpunjabi/pen/ejZdae

Comment: Added an answer please check. Link to codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mjPzbZ?editors=1100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are having a div inside a p tag, thats causing the issue, Change your structure and CSS like shown below.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.abc {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  font: 100px/1em sans-serif;
  top: 50vh;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

input {
  visibility: hidden;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

input+label:before {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  content: "\00a0";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 1em 0 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

input:checked+label:before {
  border: none;
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
  content: "\2713";
  text-align: center;
}

input:checked+label:after {
  font-weight: bold;
}

input:focus+label::before {
  outline: rgb(59, 153, 252) auto 5px;
}

.def {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-140%, -50%);
  z-index: -1;
}

span {
  background: green;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 55%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -55%);
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

span:nth-child(1) {
  left: 120%;
  /*  background:green; */
}

span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 115%;
  /*  background:red; */
}

span:nth-child(3) {
  left: -10%;
  /*  background:blue; */
}

span:nth-child(4) {
  top: -10%;
  /*  background:yellow; */
}


/* styles for  span when checkbox is checked */

input:checked~div span {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="abc">
  <input type="checkbox" id="c1" />
  <label for="c1">c1</label>
  <div class="def">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

Put some content inside your span, it's working.

```css
input:checked ~ div span{
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="c1">
<label for="c1">c1</label>
<div>
    <span>Red Text</span>
    <span>Red alert</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

A span doesn't have anything inside, and takes up no space, by default. Your code works for me if I add text inside the span.